# Python: error using using eval() while converting string into name of numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, eval

I have two `numpy`arrays named `dec_pair` and `dec_community` in a module named `config.py`, initialized to zero:

```
dec_pair = numpy.zeros(200)
dec_community = numpy.zeros(200)
```

Now, I am trying to access them from some other module, say `roc.py`, where their names are being formed based on a input variable, i.e.

```
import config
def dosomething(name):
    local_name = 'config.py'+name
    eval(local_name)[i:] += 1
```

where `name` can be `pair` or `community`. The issue is, `eval(local_name)` is returning the length of the `numpy` array i.e. `200` here and not the array itself, which gives me this error:

> ValueError: cannot slice a 0-d array

However, when I do the same thing on the python interpreter, it runs smoothly :

```
>>> dec_pair = numpy.zeros(5)
>>> name = 'pair'
>>> local_name = 'dec_'+name
>>> eval(local_name)
array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])
```

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong and what would be the correct way to do it ?

Comment: 1) Huh?  I can't understand this code.  did you import `config` and it has variables like `config.pydec_pair`?  2) this code design seems fishy and eval us unsafe.  3) did you mean to initialize the arrays like `numpy.zeros(200)` instead of `numpy.array(200)`?

Comment: ok I made too many typos in this question :| ..yes I meant to initialize it like `nump.zeros(200)`, made a mistake while typing ..I want to access it and modify it from the module `roc.py`

Comment: But... are there variables like `config.pydec_pair`? Or what? What's the point of the `dosomething` function?

Comment: I want to be able to modify the arrays `dec_pair` and `dec_community` from the module `roc.py` , which receives the name of the array to  be modified on as an input. Therefore, I am trying to access the correct array based on the parameter `name`. Maybe I did this horribly wrong .. what is the correct method to achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're trying to do looks like a **bad idea** (although I'm having a hard time figuring out what you're trying to do).

My first instinct is to say that you probably want `numpy.zeros(200)` instead of `numpy.array(200)` in your config file.

Second, if this stuff is imported, you could probably use `globals()[local_name]` or `vars(config)[local_name]` to get your data rather than `eval`, although that is still definitely bad practice (in other words, **Please don't do this -- see point 3**).

Third, when you don't know the name of the variable ahead of time, **you should be using a dictionary to begin with**  e.g.

```
#config.py
dec={'pair':np.zeros(200), 'community':np.zeros(200)}
```

Now you just access them in your function as:

```
a=config.dec[name]
a[i:]+=1
```

If you wanted an easier handle on `dec_pair` and `dec_community`, you could do `config.py` like this:

```
dec_pair=np.zeros(200)
dec_community=np.zeros(200)
dec={'pair':dec_pair, 'community':dec_community}
```

Although I would probably say that it's best to keep the data referenced in only 1 place so I would caution against doing this unless you really **need** to keep an API consistent or something.

Finally, you haven't mentioned what the value of the variable `i` is -- accessing variables outside of the current namespace is often risky, and variables named `i` are probably even more risky.

Comment: +1 to everything except the `globals` and `vars` bit. Don't suggest that, it's bad practice.

Comment: @ColinDunklau -- Agreed.  I added a statement saying "Please don't do this".  However, I have used those functions once or twice (and only once or twice) so I think it's good to know that they are there and what exactly they do.

Comment: OK I get that ! I will modify my design to take into account your suggestions ! Thanks Colin and mgilson !

Comment: Can you comment as to why it is actually not good to use them ? why do they exist and situations where they can be useful ?

Comment: @R.Bahl Global variables detract from readability and logical separation. More to the point, code that uses global variables can be absolute hell to debug, since it's not easy to identify where they the value comes from. In my (limited) experience, they're only useful in the debugger.

Comment: @R.Bahl -- `eval` is unsafe.  It allows the user to run untrusted code.  My experience using `globals`, `locals` and `vars` has basically been limited to sanitizing input for `eval` in order to make it safe in places where I have no choice but to let the user enter input.  Even there it would probably be better for me to use `ast` to parse the input string, but I haven't dug in enough to learn that stuff -- They're also useful for helping me remember what I've done in an interactive session...

Comment: @ColinDunklau -- Good point about readability and logical separation.  I think that's a better argument against them than the difficulty to debug -- although those are probably just 2 sides of the same coin.

Comment: @mgilson: Even after removing `eval()` and using dictionary to access name, the original problem still persists i.e. the error `ValueError: cannot slice a 0-d array`. Still return the length of the array and not the array ilself

Comment: @R.Bahl -- What happens if you try to print the array?  what does it look like?  Are you sure you're initializing with np.zeros?  that's the exact error message I get if I do:  `np.array(200)[:]`.

Comment: ok i figured it out. You guys were right all along. It was a result of a bad design.

Comment: yes. It had done done that mistake and some how had been overlooking it :| feel kind of stupid now :|

Answer (score 5):

Yuck.

First of all, don't use `eval()`. You're gonna have a bad time.

Secondly, just import the config! In `roc.py`:

```
def dosomething(numpy_array):
    return somefunction(numpy_array)
```

In some other module:

```
import roc
import config
someresult = roc.somefunction(config.dec_pair)
```

Edit: After re-reading your question, I believe you're trying to use global values. This is almost always an indication of poor design. You should restrict your use of the "global" variables to a single script, and use functions to pass those objects around.

Comment: Colin: I thought it was implied that I was obviously importing `config`. I have edited my code to reflect that. `dosomething()` gets called from a third module say `foo.py`, which passes it the argument `name`

Comment: @R.Bahl don't pass names. Pass objects.

Comment: +1 for "don't use `eval()`, you're gonna have a bad time ..."